# Lookup items in firebase then lookup docId from the first returned items then merge

Tags: firebase, rxjs

I need to lookup the location for each product.
First `searchCollection` returns array of object with one of the property `anotherTblDocIs` as a json string.
In this json string, which is firebase docId, I need to lookup the name. Then I need to merge it back.

How can I achieve this properly?

```
this.firebaseService
        .searchCollection('product', 'shopId', this.shopId)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap((products: any) => {
            let observableBatch = [];
            products.map(product => {
              const docIds = JSON.parse(product['anotherTblDocIs']);
              
              docIds.forEach(doc =>{
                observableBatch.push(this.firebaseService.readCollectionByDocId('doc', doc ).pipe(map(u => {return { doc, ...u}})))
              });
            });
            return forkJoin(observableBatch);
          })
        )
        .subscribe(products => {

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a stream it's often better to break things into small steps, and you keep transforming the stream until what you need.

Maybe this won't be exactly equivalent in terms of orders of subscriptions, but I think it would look better with something like:

```
this.firebaseService.searchCollection('product', 'shopId', this.shopId).pipe(
  // Here we have Observable<Product[]>

  mergeMap(products => products)
  // Now we have Observable<Product>

  mergeMap(product => JSON.parse(product['anotherTblDocIds']))
  // Now we have Observable<DocIds> (for each product)

  mergeMap(docId => this.firebaseService.readCollectionByDocId('doc', doc).pipe(
    // We need to this map inside this stream to have the reference to `docId`
    map(u => ({ doc: docId, ...u }))
  ))
)
```

`mergeMap` will flatten both Observables and arrays, so it can be used this way.